# Unity3d. Get same component for duplicated GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a gameObject (`myObject`) and a component that attached somewhere in that gameObject (`myComponent`).


I duplicate game object:

```
var duplicate = Instantiate(myObject);
```

And then I want to have reference to the same component, but on my `duplicate` gameObject.

Is there a way to get same component on duplicated object?

I tried to get component by index, but is is not work for hierarchy of game objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all of you.

I was needed something like this:

```
public static T GetSameComponentForDuplicate<T>(T c, GameObject original, GameObject duplicate)
    where T : Component
{
    // remember hierarchy
    Stack<int> path = new Stack<int>();

    var g = c.gameObject;
    while (!object.ReferenceEquals(g, original))
    {
        path.Push(g.transform.GetSiblingIndex());
        g = g.transform.parent.gameObject;
    }

    // repeat hierarchy on duplicated object
    GameObject sameGO = duplicate;
    while (path.Count != 0)
    {
        sameGO = sameGO.transform.GetChild(path.Pop()).gameObject;
    }

    // get component index
    var cc = c.gameObject.GetComponents<T>();
    int componentIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < cc.Length; i++)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(c, cc[i]))
        {
            componentIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    // return component with the same index on same gameObject
    return sameGO.GetComponents<T>()[componentIndex];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a copy of component but since component can have only 1 parent (gameObject) this means 1 component instance cannot be shared with 2 game objects.

Otherwise if you are OK with having 2 separate instances of component on both game objects, you could create Prefab out of gameObject (with component) and instantiate prefab.

Considering that you might have multiple components of the same type, but with different settings (properties) and you want to find component with the same settings you would have to use [GetComponents](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponents.html) and loop through results to find a new (duplicated) component with exactly the same settings.

Considering (for simplicity) you look for property called Id:

```
MyComponent myObjectsComponent = ... // here logic to find it, etc
GameObject duplicate = Instantiate(myObject);
List<MyComponent> myComponents = duplicate.GetComponents<MyComponent>();

// This can be replaced with bellow LINQ
MyComponent foundComponent = null;
foreach(MyComponent c in myComponents) {
  if (c.Id=myObjectsComponent.Id) {
    foundComponent = c;
    break;
  }
}
```

Alternatively you could use LINQ to simplify loop:

```
MyComponent foundComponent = (from c in myComponents where c.Id=myObjectsComponent.Id select c).FirstDefault<MyComponent>();
```

Comment: 1 component == 1 gameObject - is okay. But suppose I have difficult calculation to find component I need. And then duplicate root game object. How to find same (duplicated) component on duplicated gameObject?

Comment: As I understand: 1. You look for component instance using complex rules, 2. When you found component instance - you duplicate it's game object 3. You want to get access to the same component (type) on newly created game object?

Comment: Yes, but not same type certainly, because I can have many of components of the same type. Maybe index or something else

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var duplicate = Instantiate(myObject) as GameObject;
var componentDup = duplicate.GetComponent<__YOUR_COMPONENT__>();
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html

Comment: This code can return different component of the same type. But I need the same component

Comment: Oh sorry, I think Instantiate method will create another class and instance into new gameobject so .... it alway diffrence.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I'm going to have a go at trying to understand what you want as well... My interpretation is that you want a reference to a specific `myComponent` on your `duplicateObject`. Very well, this is how you could do it:

```
public class MyObject : MonoBehaviour {

    // Create a reference variable for the duplicate to have
    public Component theComponent { get; set; }

    void Start()
    {
        // Save the component you want the duplicate to have
        theComponent = GetComponent<Anything>(); 

        // Create the duplicate
        var duplicate = Instantiate(gameObject);

        // Set the component reference to the saved component
        duplicate.GetComponent<MyObject>().theComponent = theComponent;
    }

}
```

This way you should have a reference to the same component in all your instances of the object. You could also just create a script that holds a static reference to the specific component, which every script can reach without instantiating anything.

```
using UnityEngine;
public class DataHolder {
    public static Component theComponent;
}
```